# Auto-Mount SD-card formatted as ext4 on ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, automount, sd-card, chroot

I try to use an MicroSD card containing a chroot environment which I can break, e.g. by installing software, [without damaging the OS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/620740/recommended-way-to-install-regularcli-deb-packages-on-ubuntu-phone) on my bq Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition, however I can not let the filesystem being auto-mounted and use the chroot at the same time.

- ext4 and similiar filesystems do not get mounted by [ciborium](https://launchpad.net/ciborium/) → by default the sd card is not mounted when using ext4, an error is indicated and I am asked to format the disk as vfat
- vfat does not support the execute permission → I cannot run programs of the chroot when the chroot is saved on a vfat partition
- To me there is no known way to start a script automatically on startup (I have found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/613557/how-to-autostart-a-shell-script-on-ubuntu-touch/622484) while searching for an answer) without changing the file-system which is by default intentionally mounted as read-only → I can not easily create a mount script executed on startup

So I wonder whether there is a way to auto-mount an MicroSD-card which can be used to store an chroot without modifying the write-protected parts of the phone.

Comment: You can call to the script in /etc/rc.local. But previously you need remount loop0 like rw because it is only read. (sudo mount /dev/loop0 / -o remount, rw)

Answer (score 0):

I have ext2 partition on my sd card and I want automount for this partition. Here is my solution for Ubuntu Touch BQ Aquaris m10.

At first, we make a system partition writable:

```
sudo touch /userdata/.writable_image
```

After doing this system will reboot.
Then, we edit `/lib/init/fstab`:

```
sudo nano /lib/init/fstab
```

and add this string in bottom:

```
/dev/mmcblk1p2  /home/phablet/mnt/sd      ext2            defaults,noatime,nodiratime,errors=remount-ro 0 2
```

Then, we make system partition read-only again:

```
sudo rm /userdata/.writable_image
```

And rebooting:

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

It works!

Comment: I haven't tested it, but it requires changing the root fs. As far as I have read, this is discouraged beacause it can lead to undefined behaviour in case of updates - a reflash of the device might become necessary, and I would prefer to avoid that case. So I do not want to change my root fs - there is a reason why it is read-only.

Comment: Some changing in rootfs can be done without problems. **[Please, read carefully comments before answer and the answer of Larry Price in this topic concerning it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/836068/how-to-properly-increase-dpi-for-desktop-apps-installed-inside-libertine)**. Larry (as far I understand) is from Canonical Team.