# How to properly increase DPI for Desktop Apps installed inside Libertine?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, display-resolution, bq, m10, libertine

It concerns Auqaris BQ M10 FHD with nice 10" screen. I tried to use the trick: create file

```
~/.local/share/libertine-container/user-data/my-container/.Xdefaults
```

and set `Xft.dpi: 224` inside it (see [xmir-setup on XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/ubuntu-touch/help/easier-xmir-setup-t3303981)).

This trick helps for Geany, Firefox, LibreOffice, but doesn't help for Djview4. Trick works with DPI for fonts, but doesn't for menu icons and pictures. An other way I know can found [there](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16475233/), I didn't test it, because of necessary to made system part writable.

I think this problem is similar to HiDPI with Retina in Linux. In usual Linux we can try to use

```
  Section "Monitor"
        Identifier     "<default monitor>"
        Option        "DPI" "224 x 224"
    EndSection
```

in `xorg.conf.d/90-monitor.conf` or use `xrandr --dpi 224`. But we have Libertine and I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: DPI is a known issue in libertine apps on high-resolution screens. The current suggested workaround is to set the system to read-writable and update the line in `/usr/bin/libertine-xmir` to be `exec Xmir -dpi 144 -title @ $@` like in the link you included. This is a temporary workaround that should be fixed eventually, but it gets the job done for now on the M10. I'd be very interested if you found a better alternative.

Comment: FYI here's the bug I mentioned: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libertine/+bug/1572888

Comment: Is it risky to set the system to read-writable? What is best way to set so?  For example with using these: `phablet-config writable-image` or `touch /userdata/.writable_image` or  `android-gadget-service enable writable`? Could I possible to get OTA after this?

Comment: I would use `phablet-config writable-image`. You'll still receive OTA updates unless you start removing parts of the system that deal with updates. Avoid using `apt` if you want to continue getting OTA updates.

Comment: Ok, Larry. I'll try to test this method, and if it will work for my applications, I will set is as answer. In any case, I don't know how to apply other methods  like `xrandr --dpi 224` in Libertine.

Comment: Larry, **check me, please:** status ``writable`` doesn't  impact on getting OTA, or I should remove this status (for example like ``rm /userdata/.writable_image``) after my work to get OTA in the future?

Comment: Making the tablet writable alone is not enough to prevent OTAs from installing, but performing various actions on the filesystem could cause issues. I would recommend removing the `.writable_image` file when you're finished to prevent any accidents. I can fashion an answer from our comment discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DPI is a known issue in libertine apps on high-resolution screens, currently captured in this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libertine/+bug/1572888

The suggested workaround for the M10 FHD is mentioned in the pastebin linked in the question, but I'll post the important parts here for future readers.

Make the tablet temporarily writable:

```
phablet-config writable-image
```

Perform a restart on the tablet, and then log in with `adb` or `phablet-shell`. Edit the file `/usr/bin/libertine-xmir` and change the exec line:

```
exec Xmir -dpi 144 -title @ $@
```

where `144` is your preferred DPI number. Once finished editing, I recommend making the tablet read-only again:

```
sudo rm /userdata/.writable_image
```

The next time you restart, your tablet will be in readonly mode again. The change to `/usr/bin/libertine-xmir` could be reverted by any updates to libertine (OTA or otherwise). Hopefully this issue will be prioritized eventually and we won't need this hack.

Comment: Larry, I've tested it and can say the result is similar of using ``.Xdefaults`` file. The font's size works, icon's size does not. (Unfortunately, I deleted Djview4, it would be interesting to see the effect of new method in this application. It was bad with font size, and the size of icons previously.)  Title of windows is very thin in both cases. But thanks for very nice "howto" about writable-status!